# What is the algorithm to select random validators in PoS?

Tags: proof-of-stake, randomness

As I know, Ethereum Casper PoS implementation randomly selects 250 validators from the validator poll for an epoch. What is the random algorithm for this selection?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about casper but POS algortihms in general use two common  methods which are **Randomised Block Selection** and **Coin Age Selection**.

In the first, validators are selected based on a combination of the lowest hash value and highest stakes. Whereas, in the Coin Age method, validators are chosen based on how long their tokens have been staked for.

Comment: Coin age does sound super deterministic to be. What is random about it? Do staked coins get "kicked out" at some point?

Comment: Do you have a source for that answer?